# Specify rootfs mount options

Tags: embedded, images, buildroot

I would like to specify mount options for my rootfs as per instructed [here](https://linux-f2fs-devel.narkive.com/cND2je9J/f2fs-mount-o-sync-sync-and-cut-off-power) however I am unsure where this should be done. I've looked through the [genimage docs](https://github.com/pengutronix/genimage/blob/master/README.rst) and there was no generic option to pass a mount option to a generic partition.

I found a similar thread [here](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2016-June/165330.html) but the answer was somewhat inconclusive.

Comment: I would add [rootflags](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt?h=linux-5.4.y#n4277) with [CONFIG_CMDLINE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CMDLINE.html) (see also CONFIG_CMDLINE_BOOL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 0.

Using @A.B 's comment, I added `rootflags=fastboot` to `cmdline.txt` which is passed to the kernel on boot. This solved my issue.